# Doing key combos with jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, keyboard-shortcuts, jkey

I'm curious how i, with the following jQuery plugin code im writing at the bottom of this question, could implement key combos. How it's working so far is it allows a user to create key commands simply by doing a normal jQuery like syntax and provide an event for the key command, like so:

```
$(window).jkey('a',function(){
   alert('you pressed the a key!');
});
```

or

```
$(window).jkey('b c d',function(){
   alert('you pressed either the b, c, or d key!');
});
```

and lastly what i want is the ability to do, but can't figure out:

```
$(window).jkey('alt+n',function(){
   alert('you pressed alt+n!');
});
```

I know how to do this outside of the plugin (on keyup set a var false and on keydown set the var true and check if the var is true when you press the other key), but i don't know how to do this when you dont know what keys are going to be pressed and how many. How do I add this support? I want to be able to allow them to do things like `alt+shift+a` or `a+s+d+f` if they wanted. I just can't get my head around how to implement this. Any ideas?

I'm going to release this as an open source plugin and i'd love to give whoever gives me the right, working, answer some credit on the blog post and in the code it's self. Thanks in advance!

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.jkey = function(keyCombo,callback) {
    if(keyCombo.indexOf(' ') > -1){ //If multiple keys are selected
        var keySplit = keyCombo.split(' ');
    }
    else{ //Else just store this single key
        var keySplit = [keyCombo];
    }
    for(x in keySplit){ //For each key in the array...

        if(keySplit[x].indexOf('+') > -1){
            //Key selection by user is a key combo... what now?
        }
        else{
            //Otherwise, it's just a normal, single key command
        }

        switch(keySplit[x]){
            case 'a':
                keySplit[x] = 65;
                break;
            case 'b':
                keySplit[x] = 66;
                break;
            case 'c':
                keySplit[x] = 67;
                break;
            //And so on for all the rest of the keys
        }
    }
    return this.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.keydown(function(e){
            if($.inArray(e.keyCode, keySplit) > -1){ //If the key the user pressed is matched with any key the developer set a key code with...
                if(typeof callback == 'function'){ //and they provided a callback function
                    callback(); //trigger call back and...
                    e.preventDefault(); //cancel the normal
                }
            }
        });
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. Essentially what I did was created a JSON object that stores all the key codes. I then replace all the provided keys with the codes. If the keys are using the '+' to make a key combo, I then create an array of the codes out of it.

We then create another array that stores all the keys that are being pressed (keyDown add the item, keyUp removes it). On keyDown, we check if it's a single key command or combo. If it's a combo, we check it against all the currently active key presses. If they all match, we execute the callback.

This will work with any number of key combos. Only time I saw that it wasn't working is when  you use the 'alert()' to display a message on the key combo because it will no longer remove the items from the active key press array.

```
(function($) { 
  $.fn.jkey = function(keyCombo,callback) {

    // Save the key codes to JSON object
    var keyCodes = { 
      'a'   : 65,
      'b'   : 66,
      'c'   : 67,
      'alt' : 18
    };

    var x = '';
    var y = '';

    if(keyCombo.indexOf(' ') > -1){ //If multiple keys are selected
        var keySplit = keyCombo.split(' ');
    }
    else{ //Else just store this single key
        var keySplit = [keyCombo];
    }

    for(x in keySplit){ //For each key in the array...

      if(keySplit[x].indexOf('+') > -1){
        //Key selection by user is a key combo
        // Create a combo array and split the key combo
        var combo = Array();
        var comboSplit = keySplit[x].split('+');

        // Save the key codes for each element in the key combo
        for(y in comboSplit){
          combo[y] = keyCodes[ comboSplit[y] ];
        }

        keySplit[x] = combo;

      } else {
        //Otherwise, it's just a normal, single key command
        keySplit[x] = keyCodes[ keySplit[x] ];
      }

    }

    return this.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);

        // Create active keys array
        // This array will store all the keys that are currently being pressed
        var activeKeys = Array();

        $this.keydown(function(e){

          // Save the current key press
          activeKeys[ e.keyCode ] = e.keyCode;

          if($.inArray(e.keyCode, keySplit) > -1){ // If the key the user pressed is matched with any key the developer set a key code with...

            if(typeof callback == 'function'){ //and they provided a callback function
              callback(); //trigger call back and...
              e.preventDefault(); //cancel the normal
            }

          } else { // Else, the key did  not match which means it's either a key combo or just dosn't exist

            // Check if the individual items in the key combo match what was pressed
            for(x in keySplit){
              if($.inArray(e.keyCode, keySplit[x]) > -1){

                // Initiate the active variable
                var active = 'unchecked';

                // All the individual keys in the combo with the keys that are currently being pressed
                for(y in keySplit[x]) {
                  if(active != false) {
                    if($.inArray(keySplit[x][y], activeKeys) > -1){
                      active = true;
                    } else {
                      active = false;
                    }
                  }
                }

                // If all the keys in the combo are being pressed, active will equal true
                if(active === true){
                  if(typeof callback == 'function'){ //and they provided a callback function
                    callback(); //trigger call back and...
                    e.preventDefault(); //cancel the normal
                  }
                }
              }
            }

          } // end of if in array

        }).keyup(function(e) {
          // Remove the current key press
          activeKeys[ e.keyCode ] = '';
        });

    });

  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're defining `x` in the global scope.

Comment: I think the scope issue can be fixed by defining x and y like this: var x = ''; var y = ''; ?

Comment: Or better yet, we can define them by adding var in the for statement? for(var x in keySplit){...

Answer (score 5):

Use keypress instead of keyup/keydown because the latter two do not accurately protray the keycode ([reference](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html), see last paragraph).  You can reference the `altKey` `ctrlKey` and `shiftKey` boolean properties of the event object in this case...

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  var alt = e.altKey;
  var ctrl = e.ctrlKey
  var shift = e.shiftKey;
  alert("Key:" + key + "\nAlt:" + alt + "\nCtrl:" + ctrl + "\nShift:" + shift);
});
```

Also, you can use `String.fromCharCode` to translate the key code to an actual letter.

You can't trap multiple keys aside from combinations with Ctrl, Alt, and Shift.  You simply can't do it in a single event.  So throw the `a+s+d+f` idea out the window.

Note: Obviously there are certain key combinations that are used by the browser.  For instance, Alt + F usually brings up the File menu in Windows.  Ctrl + N usually launches a new window/tab.  Do *not* attempt to override any of these combinations.

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/yuucE/) for your testing pleasure.

Comment: So how do I integrate that though and how do I integrate it so that any key combination will work, e.g. shift+alt+f+d+s if they wanted. Like i said, this is for me, but it's also going to be released publicly, so i still need to allow then to override browser defaults like ctrl+t although I never would :)

Comment: Oops, then, what about shift+alt+f, how do i integrate that into the plugin, sorry

Comment: You can't trap multiple keys, so forget about it.  The event is fired once per key press.  The boolean indicators simply tell you whether or not Ctrl, Alt, or Shift was held down when the key was pressed.  As far as overriding browser defaults, no, NO, and **NO!**

Comment: @Oscar In response to your second comment:  `if(key == "F" && alt && shift) { alert("OK!"); }`

Comment: @Oscar And shift+alt+f may not even work because the browser likely has something already wired up for alt+f.

Comment: And like i said, IM not going to override them, however, it'd be foolish to assume how others will use the plugin. Not to mention in other countries different keys will equal different browser events... Once again, IM not going to override them, that'd be annoying.

Comment: shift+alt+f seems to work fine also... just alt+f does conflict (im not using that tho...) I'm personally looking to use alt+s, alt+n, alt+l, ctrl+alt+leftArrow and ctrl+alt+rightArrow,

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark but maybe it'll help you down the right path.

If it's possible to have that function recognize a hexadecimal value for the key that you entered instead of the literal key (such as 0x6E for the letter 'n'), you could derive what "alt+n" translates to in hex and have the function look out for that value.

Comment: Awh, interesting, ill look into it. Thanks! Also, do you have a reference on how to convert them via JS? I haven't Googled yet...

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for something that will let a user easily enter and define key combos using a plain input box, I wrote a plugin that does it for you: http://suan.github.com/jquery-keycombinator/