# Handling Combo Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to simulate GMail/Twitter keyboard shortcuts of pressing a key, followed by another key to navigate somewhere in jQuery.

For example, <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>H</kbd> to go "Home" in GMail. Twitter also has <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>H</kbd> and other "combo" shortcuts.

Is there a jQuery plugin that simulates this behaviour?

Comment: You mean something like this : https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys help...?

Comment: I haven't seen a way to have combo shortcuts with the jquery.hotkeys plugin. You can do multiple keypresses (like Ctrl+A), but not G, H. If I am mistaken, I would be very pleased, as I already want to use this plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just released a library last week called mousetrap that has this functionality built in.  Check out http://craig.is/killing/mice

You can do

```
Mousetrap.bind('g h', function() {
    console.log('go home!');
});
```

Comment: Tyvm for this awesome lib!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about plugins, but you can achieve this other wise by keeping a key queue and processing that queue on each mouseup.

i.e. Something like:

```
var myKeyQueue = [];

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var code e.charCode != 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    myKeyQueue.push(code);
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    processKeyQueue();
});
```

And you processKeyQueue function will be something like:

```
function processKeyQueue() {

    // check if the Q contains any actionable key-combo, if so do it!
    /*
    if(myKeyQueue.length == 2) {
        if(String.fromCharCode(myKeyQueue[0]) == 'G' &&  String.fromCharCode(myKeyQueue[0]) == 'H') {
            // you code here ...
        }
    }
    */

    if(myKeyQueue.length >= 2) {
        myKeyQueue = []; // remove all keys in Q
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Doing key combos with jQuery / JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074645/doing-key-combos-with-jquery-javascript) I think that it will answer your problem. Also [this guy](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/16/ctrl-key-combination-simple-jquery-plugin/) wrote his own VERY small plugin to handle CTRL+[Any Key] listener so that he could use shortcuts like CTRL+S to call a function that saves the active document, it might be able to be modified for your use

Answer (score 0):

I think this: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/
might help in some way for adding your own shotcuts